# Mongodb: Query and array with an array

Tags: mongodb

I'm kind of stuck how to query an array with an array, in mongodb.

In the below example, "tag" is a string - and "newTotalTags" is an array of tags.

```
  let allShares = await ShareModel.find({tag: { $in: newTotalTags}}).lean()
```

I need to change this logic from tag (single string) to tags (array).
So I have an array (newTotalTags) and I need to query a schema property which is also an array.

Any tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try [$all](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/all/) instead of `$in`,

```
let allShares = await ShareModel.find({ tag: { $all: newTotalTags } }).lean()
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/KpOCuqB9phq)